# A saying for 'using the right tools to do the right job'

Tags: proverb-requests

Any ideas for a saying that means the opposite of using a sledgehammer to crack a nut? Basically I need something that means if the problem is big, then don't underestimate it, and make sure you have the right tool

Comment: Are you asking for a term meaning the use of enough tool, or, simply the right tool?

Comment: Using the right tool (basically, I'm trying to explain why email is not always the right channel to reach employees). That sometimes you need to consider bigger, better, more visible ways to get employee attention

Comment: Use the right hammer!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is in the question : '**the right tool for the job**' sometimes (as in the question) stated as 'the right tool for the right job'.

> One of my grandfather’s favorite sayings was “Use the right tool for the job”—common-sense advice that applies to a wide range of situations.

[Dr Dobbs](http://www.drdobbs.com/the-right-tool-for-the-job/184415067)

Relevant to the context of the question is :

> Communication : **Choosing the right tool for the job**

[Automation World](https://www.automationworld.com/article/technologies/communication-protocols-standards/communication-choosing-right-tool-job)

Answer (score 3):

***If your only tool is a hammer, every problem looks like a nail.***

From [Quote Investigator](https://quoteinvestigator.com/2014/05/08/hammer-nail/); also [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_instrument).

The implication is that different problems require different solutions (or tools).

Answer (score 3):

"Don't bring a knife to a gun fight."

Comment: This might benefit from a little more explanation.

Comment: Please add references.

Answer (score 2):

I've used "Horses for courses" in this context, but it also means something more like everyone has their calling. It's pretty loose though, and I think it can be used to mean the same as "to each their own" too.

[Horses for courses - Cambridge English dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/horses-for-courses)

Answer (score -1):

**Go in loaded for bear**

> *loaded for bear* phrase [North American] [informal]
>
> Fully prepared for any eventuality, especially a confrontation or
>   challenge.
>
> ‘as my ancestors were wont to say, watch out, John Bull, I'm loaded
>   for bear!’

[[ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/loaded_for_bear)]